# Ubuntu Server Edition

Tags: ubuntu, web, database, lamp

I just installed the lasted version of Ubuntu server with LAMP my goals to build my own site and database (php mysql).

1. is there a list of all the useful commands somewhere?
2. is there a good how to somewhere?
3. now what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. You'll likely be logging in to a Bash shell, so start there:
   [Bash Beginners Guide.](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)
2. Then move on to setting up LAMP:
   [Getting started with Ubuntu LAMP server.](http://www.google.com/search?q=getting+started+with+Ubuntu+LAMP+server)
3. Whatever you want.  There is [more](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=setting+up+mysql+on+ubuntu+server&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) [information](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=setting+up+apache+on+ubuntu+server&aq=f&aqi=g-l1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) [available](http://php.net/) [than](http://www.perl.org/) [anyone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388211/mattben) [could](http://python.org/) [ever](http://www.google.com/search?q=Beginners+guide+to+html) [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck).